# Elementary abelian groups

Tags: c, field, bit, finite-group-theory

I just read on Wikipedia about *elementary abelian groups* which appear to be related to bit fields. I'd be grateful if someone could explain me [this particular paragraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field#Homogeneity_and_mathematical_structure) as I strive to fully master bit fields.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The group `Z/2Z` is the set `{0,1}` together with the binary operation `+` that works as follows:

```
0 + 0 = 0
0 + 1 = 1
1 + 0 = 1
1 + 1 = 0
```

In that paragraph, the author refers to the group `(Z/2Z)^n`, which is just an ordered `n`-tuple of bits:

```
(b_1, b_2, ..., b_n)
```

where `b_i = 0` or `1`, and the binary operation `+` is taken coordinate-wise so that

```
(b_1, b_2, ..., b_n) + (d_1, d_2, ..., d_n) = (b_1+d_1, b_2+d_2, ..., b_n+d_n)
```

where `b_i+d_i` is done as in `Z/2Z`.

The *partial order* denoted `<=` that is discussed is the usual order on `Z/2Z` given by

```
0 <= 1

0 <= 0
1 <= 1
```

The last two are *reflexive*. This order is extended to `(Z/2Z)^n` coordinatewise, so that

```
(b_1, b_2, ..., b_n) <= (d_1, d_2, ..., d_n)
```

if and only if

```
b_i <= d_i for every i
```

For example, when n=2, we get the following relations:

```
(0,0) <= (0,0)
(0,0) <= (0,1)
(0,0) <= (1,0)
(0,0) <= (1,1)

(0,1) <= (0,1)
(0,1) <= (1,1)

(1,0) <= (1,0)
(1,0) <= (1,1)

(1,1) <= (1,1)
```

Notice that `(1,0)` and `(0,1)` are **incomparable** meaning that neither `(0,1) <= (1,0)` nor `(1,0) <= (0,1)`.

Comment: Is Z/2Z an equation? Shouldn't it be the same as 1/2?

Comment: @asdf: No, it's notation for the set of integers modulo 2 also known as a quotient group. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group